# Typescript number must be less than 1 and greater than 0

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a way yet, in Typescript, to ensure that the value of a number is less than and/or greater than a certain value. Right now it allows you to specify a list of values, but I don't know about comparing.

This is something like what I'm looking for:

```
interface Input {
    value: number < 1
}
```

Comment: I think you can't even list numbers yet, onlt strings. Maybe you are looking for [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/)

Comment: @TamasHegedus [It's a new feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/08/30/announcing-typescript-2-0-rc/#user-content-more-literal-types) in TypeScript 2.0.2 (the current release candidate). But still, that's just for using a literal number in a type position, e.g. `var foo : 0 | 1 | 2`

Comment: Wow, great, I didn't knew about it! TIL

Answer (score 16):

Right now there is nothing in the language to allow you to do that kind of type definition.

Comment: For anyone wondering in 2020 (4 years later) - range implementation is still discussed in this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480

Comment: about 3 and a half years later the issue is still open.

Comment: Now moved on to TypeScript [Numeric Range Types (Feature Update) #54925](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54925)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a very practical solution. And like others have pointed out there's work on TypeScript side. Nevertheless, I wrote up a hacky solution.

Limitations:

- Your comparison value must be less than 45
- Will only work for integers

Provided my utilities, here's the solution to the question you asked:

```
// Read more below to see the definitions of these variables
interface Input {
   value: AllGreaterThan<1, OneToOneHundred>
}
```

Simply, this requires `value` to be an integer between 2-99. If you're interested, here's the source code. If not, then copy and paste this into an isolated, import, and enjoy...

```
// e.g. "0|1|2" -> ["0", "1|2"]
type Decompose<S> = S extends `${infer FirstNumber}|${infer RestOfSet}` ? [FirstNumber, RestOfSet]  : never;

// Utilizes simple array indexing to get the job done. Not ideal, but it works
type OneHundredNumber= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99];
type OneToOneHundred = "0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9"|"10"|"11"|"12"|"13"|"14"|"15"|"16"|"17"|"18"|"19"|"20"|"21"|"22"|"23"|"24"|"25"|"26"|"27"|"28"|"29"|"30"|"31"|"32"|"33"|"34"|"35"|"36"|"37"|"38"|"39"|"40"|"41"|"42"|"43"|"44"|"45"|"46"|"47"|"48"|"49"|"50"|"51"|"52"|"53"|"54"|"55"|"56"|"57"|"58"|"59"|"60"|"61"|"62"|"63"|"64"|"65"|"66"|"67"|"68"|"69"|"70"|"71"|"72"|"73"|"74"|"75"|"76"|"77"|"78"|"79"|"80"|"81"|"82"|"83"|"84"|"85"|"86"|"87"|"88"|"89"|"90"|"91"|"92"|"93"|"94"|"95"|"96"|"97"|"98"|"99";
type ToNumber<T extends OneTOOneHundred> = OneHundredNumber[T]

// @ts-expect-error: ignore because typescript requires explicit matches but it's not practical here
type DecomposedNumber<S> = ToNumber<Decompose<S>[0]>

// Max is 44 so this is the only number table you need
type FortyFive = '0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|end'
type AllGreaterThan<LessThanThis extends number | string, RangeToReturn extends number, Current = FortyFive> =
  ToString<LessThanThis> extends Decompose<Current>[0]
    ? Exclude<RangeToReturn, DecomposedNumber<Current>>
    : AllGreaterThan<LessThanThis, Exclude<RangeToReturn, DecomposedNumber<Current>>, Decompose<Current>[1]>

export type OneToOneHundredNumber = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99
export type AllIntegersInRange = AllGreaterThan<44, OneToOneHundredNumber>
```